# MYSQL - get a row from a table in every database

Tags: mysql

In my mysql server I have a bunch of different databases:
db1, db2, db3 etc
I'd like to write a query to get data from the same table on each database.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Settings WHERE active = 1;
```

Obviously, I wouldn't want to query system databases.

Comment: Usually your connection object connects to a database and thereafter you select from a table within that database. You will need multiple connections if you have the same table in different databases. So you can repeat the same query on multiple connections.

Comment: This question seams to arise from bad design?

Answer (score 2):

Can you just do this?:

```
SELECT * FROM db1.Settings WHERE active = 1;
SELECT * FROM db2.Settings WHERE active = 1;
SELECT * FROM db3.Settings WHERE active = 1;
```

Comment: The problem with that is I don't know how many databases there may be. :'(

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

To create a list of available databases.

```
SHOW DATABASES (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-databases.html)
```

To check if each database has the table you want to select.

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'Settings' (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-tables.html)
```

Then select them all.